# SQL query with three different tables with distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I'm having some trouble with a SQL query across 3 tables with different attributes. Here are the tables and the attributes that I'd like to query in each of them:

> news_stories - time, headline
>
> per_minute_quotes - security_id, timestamp, last_price
>
> securities - name, id_bb, id

What I'd like to do is retrieve a security name, id from the securities table, find headlines that correspond to that security (with a timestamp) from the *news_stories* table and find the last_price for that security at the same time as the article from the per_minute_quotes table.

Does this make sense? Please see what I've managed to do so far below...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `news_stories`.`time`    
    , `securities`.`name`     
    , `adjusted_daily_quotes`.`security_id`
    , `news_stories`.`headline`
    , `securities`.`id_bb` 
    , `securities`.`id`
FROM
    `schema`.`adjusted_daily_quotes`
    , `schema`.`securities`
    , `schema`.`news_stories`
WHERE ( (`adjusted_daily_quotes`.`security_id`) = '498'
    AND (`securities`.`id`) = '498'
    AND (`securities`.`id_bb`) LIKE '267%'
    AND (`news_stories`.`headline`)  LIKE '%:267')
LIMIT 0,50;
```

This will basically do the first part of my query, ie. it isn't connected with the last_price. Here is my attempt at doing that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `news_stories`.`time`    
    , `securities`.`name`     
    , `per_minute_quotes`.`security_id`
    , `news_stories`.`headline`
    , `securities`.`id_bb` 
    , `securities`.`id`
    , `per_minute_quotes`.`timestamp`
    , `per_minute_quotes`.`last_price`
FROM
    `schema`.`per_minute_quotes`
    , `schema`.`securities`
    , `schema`.`news_stories`
WHERE ( (`per_minute_quotes`.`security_id`) = '498'
    AND (`securities`.`id`) = '498'
    AND (`securities`.`id_bb`) LIKE '267%'
    AND (`news_stories`.`headline`)  LIKE '%:267 HK'
    AND (`per_minute_quotes`.`timestamp`) <= (`news_stories`.`time`))
LIMIT 0,5;
```

However, this query returns 5 of the same headline for some reason, all with the same time. I would really appreciate help with forming this query. Does that have something to do with the DISTINCT operator? I've tried using GROUP BY but with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably by far the easiest way to do it / explain it, although there are other ways.

```
 SELECT
    s.name
    , s.id
    , ns.headline
    , pmq.last_price
 FROM
    securities s
 JOIN
     news_stories ns
      ON ns.headline LIKE '%:267 HK%'
 JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
       MAX(per_minute_quotes.timestamp) ts
       , per_minute_quotes.security_id
    FROM
       per_minute_quotes
    WHERE
       per_minute_quotes.security_id
       AND per_minute_quotes.timestamp <= news_stories.time
    GROUP BY
       per_minute_quotes.security_id
    ) t1
 JOIN
    per_minute_quotes pmq
      ON s.id = pmq.security_id
        AND t1.ts = pmq.time 
 WHERE
     security.id = '498'
 LIMIT 0,5;
```

The easiest way to do this is with joins, which you are doing, it's just a different way.  The other important thing you need, is the join with the aggregation in it (MAX).  This join is a sub-query that finds the pmq with the MAX timestamp that is less or equal to when your news story was published.  You were pretty close, just need a bit of refactoring.

*I may have mistakes in here as I typed it in Notepad and copy and pasted... and it's 4 AM and I should be in bed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Michael! Unfortunately my DB software is giving me "Error Code: 1146 Table 'per_minute_quotes.security_id' doesn't exist" when I run it. I've spent a long time trying to figure out what the problem is but can't seem to find it. Do you know what could be wrong?

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/RxEehVX5

Comment: Still can't get it to work - I used your code but it gave errors. After editing it slightly to remove the error (added line 16), it's been running for the past hour and never seems to finish... I guess it's cross-querying 3 tables but given the 5 row limit it seems weird that it takes so long. Do you have any thoughts? http://pastebin.com/WZrYwMdd